# Compare multiple Google analytic Channels

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have set 10 different Google Analytic Tags for a single website.
1. UA-XXXXXXX-1
2. UA-XXXXXXX-2
...
10.UA-XXXXXXX-10

Each channel displays different content on the same URL

Now, I have 10 different tags that all track visits on the same website.

I need to benchmark all of my channels(returning visitors, traffic, etc) to see the one that is performing better.

Is there any way to compare all against each other?
Can I create advanced segments based on the tag that I display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no need for the 10 different UAs, Google Analytics natively reports visitor access by demographics, based their location.

The solution is to use only 1 UA account, and with no further need of customizations, go into the "Demographics > Location" Report on the left-side menu, there you can segment your users based on country and city.

Also, in most of your reports, you can select "Country/Territory" as a secondary dimension by clicking the "Secondary Dimension" Drop-down under the report chart.

For more information, also check the [GA Help Center - Location](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144408)

Comment: Hello Audusto, thanks for your reply.
I dont use different UA just for loccation. that was just an example. There is no option to divide my channels in the way I want from Google. I basicly display different content for each channel and I want to compare visits from different channels

Comment: Well in that case the best use would be to still use only one UA, but with different profiles, one for each channel, and using filters you can accurately divide de content. Then, use one profile with no filter, that collects all the data, in this way you can make comparisons between them. this google presentation portrait the whole concept very well: http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/filters_v15_ad1/